# Linux taking lot of time to boot up

Tags: linux, boot

I am using 64 bit Kali Bang (modification of Kali Linux) and it is taking very long to boot up. From the log files I can see that the following step takes a very long time.

```
syslog:Dec 20 12:07:34 kali kernel: [   24.231693] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0f.0: CORB reset timeout#1, CORBRP = 0
```

What's this about and how I can fix it to speed up the boot up?

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/5976e83bf38f604d8004f17e2238021a) the complete log.

Comment: Don't use kali as desktop system.

Comment: snd_hda_intel seems to be your sound card and I think it has nothing to do with your slow boot up issue. You should add more logs information in order to help you.

Comment: @IporSircer I am using it on a laptop. BTW what difference does it make?

Comment: If you can't fix someone's problem at least don't down-vote for no reason.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio I have added the complete log. Please have a look now.

Comment: `16:36:40 kali systemd[1]: system-generators terminated by signal ALRM.` seems to be the suspicious link in your log.

Answer (score 2):

There are some hints that this could be a python/systemd bug.

The line that appears to be delaying your boot would appear to be

```
16:36:40 kali systemd[1]: system-generators terminated by signal ALRM.
```

Debian seems to have a [bug report for a system stalling for 90 seconds,](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=823337) which sounds very similar to your problem, and it sounds like the system is blocking on random number generation.

> The first line I get in dmesg after typing something at the keyboard is "random: nonblocking pool is initialized"
>
> systemd-cron does uses Python's hashlib to compute md5's; but that doesn't need any source of randomness at all.
>
> Now I see even an empty python program with only the shebang line would still trigger this delay; so this had to be a python runtime related bug.

And

> We believe that the bug you reported is fixed in the latest version of python3.5

So as a first step try updating your version of Python 3.5

Comment: I have anaconda3 installed on my linux. I hope `apt-get install python3.5` will update my Python. Right?

Comment: @Lokesh you would hope, but not using Kali (or Kali Bang) I don't know for sure. It depends on how well their repos are kept up to date. An `apt-get update` might even do it, but again it's up to you as only you know how or what your system has installed so far.